# Using the Django ManyToMany relationship example. Need to initialization first?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Just finished the Django tutorial.  Starting my own project.  Using the ManyToMany Relationship example [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/tests/modeltests/many_to_many/models.py).  I added in the following controls in my admin.py:

```
class ArticleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Article
    extra = 3

class PublicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ArticleInline]

admin.site.register(Publication, PublicationAdmin)
```

But when I try to add a publication in the admin page, it says:

```
<class 'polls.models.Article'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'polls.models.Publication'>
```

Do I have to initialize an article before I can create a publication?  Does creating a publication make Django look for an article?

Thanks for the help.  Just starting out.  It's pretty overwhelming, but very exciting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a many to many relationship, you need to access the actual through model.

I'm assuming you have something like:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    [...]  # your other stuff
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
```

Assuming that construction, you access the `through` model using the attribute spelled similarly:

```
class ArticleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Publication.articles.through
    [...]  # whatever else you need
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Thanks for taking the time to answer such a noob question, it wasn't in the example, but I guess I should do more reading/tutorials first.